# Cartoon about a boy and a robot in a red cape

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

My friend is looking for a cartoon about a boy and a robot in a red cape (the robot itself is not red, it is dressed in a red cape). The action takes place in the desert, where they were preparing for some kind of battle. The cartoon was 3d. A friend saw it in 2006-2008, but does not remember on which channel

Comment: A robot in a red cape makes me think of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oGxbCc0Xq8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Eon Kid](https://eonkid.fandom.com/wiki/Eonkid_Wiki) ([IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1001471/), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_Kid)) (or [Iron kid](https://brb.es/iron-kid/)) has a robot in a red cape [Gaff](https://eonkid.fandom.com/wiki/Gaff), who is the robot guardian of the Eon family, and in particular [Marty](https://eonkid.fandom.com/wiki/Marty_(Eon_Kid)), the protagonist. Marty wears and wields an Iron Fist, an heirloom of his family, and goes on a quest to destroy the tyrannical robot General. When wielding the fist, he can equip his ancestor's armour, giving him superhuman abilities.

It fits the time scale well, first airing in the US in 2007.

[image]

Found with google search `3d cartoon robot desert boy`

Comment: Yes! This is it! Thank you very much

Comment: Heh... I actually Googled this one, thinking it might be likely, but didn't see the cape in the images. Good catch!

Answer (score -1):

The first thing that comes to mind is Fullmetal Alchemist, although in that one the boy (with a metal arm) wore the cape.  The robot was generally gray, although in some scenes he had red trim.[image: Promotional art]

Comment: Also the "robot" is an empty suit of armor.

Comment: @lfurini True, but it could reasonably be described as a robot by someone not remembering it completely.  Looks like it's not the answer anyway.